# Как выяснить с какого сайта на vds linux сервере идет Dos атака?

Tags: linux, dos

Получил от техподдержки где размещен vds письмо: Кратко "якобы с одного из вашего сайта идет атака. Поступила жалоба. Но мы не скажем/не входит в обязанности. Вот типа логи человека, который пожаловался. Устраняйте. А еще лучше мы устраним за 4500 за сайт." 
Вопрос как мне вычислить правда ли это? Помогите, пожалуйста

Выдержка из логов которые прислал автор жалобы:

```
we detected a DOS attack from your network.
Below the logs.
------------------------------------------
МойАйПиСервера - - [05/Mar/2020:12:15:35 +0100] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2028 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
МойАйПиСервера - - [05/Mar/2020:12:15:36 +0100] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2423 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
МойАйПиСервера - - [05/Mar/2020:12:15:37 +0100] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2028 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
МойАйПиСервера - - [05/Mar/2020:12:15:38 +0100] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2391 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"
МойАйПиСервера - - [05/Mar/2020:12:15:39 +0100] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2028 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0"


И так далее.... на 5 страниц ворда
```

Пробую настроить логи исх трафика.

```
 sudo tcpdump 'port 80' and src host МойАйПиСервера -w /tmp/http.log
```

исх трафик в логах на левые сайты подтвердился, но откуда идет пока не могу вычислить :( Может запрос к tcpdump другой нужен? Можно вычислить от какого файла идет обращение?

Comment: Что подразумевается под атакой? Трафиком давят того клиента или соединения открывают немеряно? Может почтовой рассылкой засыпают? Что хоть в логах пишет? Посмотреть на своем сервере объем исходящего трафика, количество установленных/устанавливаемых соединений, объем и количество отосланных писем. Переехать на другого хостера, в конце концов.

Comment: @Morewind , "Тот клиент" прислал логи где много POST и GET запросов на их сервер с моего. Пробую настроить логи исх трафика.  _sudo tcpdump 'port 80' and src host МойАйПиСервера -w /tmp/http.log_,   исх трафик в логах на левые сайты подтвердился, но откуда идет пока не могу вычислить :( Может запрос к tcpdump другой нужен? Можно вычислить от какого файла идет обращение?

Comment: Команда наподобие `netstat -ntp | grep :80` покажет список процессов с ESTABLISHED соединениями в куда-то там (если не покажет, то может попали в паузу между запросами и стоит запустить ещё раз), можно пробежаться по PID и посмотреть кто это

Comment: @andreymal, есть запросы с ESTABLISHED, а не подскажите как   пробежаться по PID и посмотреть кто это?

Comment: @Владимир любым диспетчером процессов, например htop, да хоть в папочку `/proc/номер` вручную сходить и содержимое посмотреть

Comment: Разные бывают ситуации. Меня провайдер вообще выключил. Он сказал, что мой роутер взломали. Я пыхтел и искал причину. Оказывается видео камеры наблюдения маячат на производителя. *( Раз в секунду.)* По-сути раз в секунду это не много, паузы очень длинные для компов. Результат : блокирование маяков и смена провайдера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таком случае рекомендую для начала воспользоваться советами как [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/188878/) и поискать в своих php файлах вредоносный код.

1. Остановить свой веб-сервер, проверить tcpdump'ом прекратились ли запросы. Если прекратились, то искать вредоносный код в сайтах.
2. Если после остановки запросы на чужой сай не прекратились, то через firewall запретить исходящие соединения на 80 порт, на работу сайтов это не повлияет (если на самом сервере нет никого, кто ходит в интернет на другие сайты).

Другими словами, вначале остановить атаку и разгрузить чужой сайт от своих запросов, потом искать у себя. Я более чем уверен, что проблема решиться пунктом 1 с остановкой вебсервера. После остановки проверять все скрипты на сайте как написано по ссылке выше.

Comment: @ Morewind, Спасибо Большое

Comment: Еще вариант, но сразу не подскажу как именно - включить в php лог для всех функций связанных с запросами по сети. Кажется есть такое, тогда можно увидеть какие файлы делают запросы.

Comment: @Morewind не факт, что запросы идут из php

Comment: @Morewind, а как через firewall запретить все исходящие соединения на 80 порт?

Comment: @Владимир  sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP но это очень временное и неудобное решение. После остановки веб сервера запросы не прекратились?

Comment: @Morewind, Не успел остановить, пришла новая жалоба... сейчас выключу все исходящие, а ночью буду решать по Вашей инструкции. Спасибо